# Concat several nodes xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Result>
   <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|</Answer>
   <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|</Answer>
</Result>
```

I want to concat each `node()` into a UNIQUE variable (`<xsl:variable name = "var"/>` for example) using `xsl:for-each` or something like that, then count the "|" char using this:

```
<xsl:variable name="total" select="string-length(string($var))-string-length(translate(string($var),'|',''))"/>
```

If i do this:

```
    <xsl:value-of select ="//Result/Answer[@questionId = 'Servicios']//text()"/>
<!--The return is something like an array-->
<!--[1]Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|-->
<!--[2]Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|-->
<!--and the result is '2' it only select the [1] and i need all of them, [1] and [2] in this case-->
```

I think i must concatenate all the values with `xsl:for-each`

im using xslt `version="1.0"`

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Lopez: What would be the result of this concatenation?

Comment: @Alejandro Something like "Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|"

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest and simplest XSLT transformation that produces the wanted result. An extensive explanation is also provided. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given document, you can concatenate pretty simple with `normalize-space(Result)` but note that it is not even necessary in your count code.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(Result)-
            string-length(translate(Result,'|',''))"/> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

just outputs the result '5' without even using a `for-each`.

**UPDATE** after OP's edit:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Answer[@questionId='Servicios']"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="total" select="string-length($var)-
            string-length(translate($var,'|',''))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just using the default template now (still no `for-each`), also referred to as *built-in template rule*, as defined in [section 5.8 of the W3C XSLT 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Comment: Using `copy-of` instead of `apply-templates` yields the same results here. No need to strip whitespace for this particular problem; should you require it later preferably use `strip-space` over `normalize-space()` (see Dimitre's answer).

Answer (score 3):

**The shortest/simplest XSLT transformation that produces the wanted result** (the concatenation of the string-values of the `Answer` elements) **is this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Result>
    <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|</Answer>
    <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|</Answer>
</Result>
```

**exactly the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|
```

**Explanation**:

1. The string value of the root node `/` is the concatenation of all of its text-node descendents.
2. The `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` directive eliminates from the XML document all unwanted whitespace-only text nodes.

**Update**: If the XML document is more complex than the provided one and some filtering is required, here is a general and simple solution, using the same idea:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStrings">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[@questionId='Servicios']"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vStrings"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (note that we must exclude the second `<Answer>`):

```
<Result>
    <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|</Answer>
    <Answer questionId="X">Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|</Answer>
    <Answer questionId="Servicios">Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|</Answer>
</Result>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Auditoría|Asesoría en Impuestos|Auditoría|Outsourcing|Asesoría en RRHH|
```

Comment: Yes, `string(/Result)` with that `xsl:strip-space` declaration will do that. Besides the counting requirement, it looks from the bad formulated question that some filtering would be needed (on `@questionId`). Maybe a RTF variable with `xsl:copy-of select="/Result/Answer[@questionId='Servicios']"`...

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, thanks for making me aware of this requirement. I have updated my solution to also include filtering.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- This will concatenate the nodes with a comma in between.  Is this what you want?-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="Answer/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```